# Does it matter how small $\epsilon$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If I'm trying to prove that a function is continuous at a certain point, and through my argument I needed that $\epsilon < \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is some known positive constant (say $1$ or $10^{-1000}$), it doesn't really matter, does it?

I know that the definition of continuity is: $\forall \ \epsilon > 0$ etc., but what is really meant is: for any arbitrarily small quantity $\epsilon$, etc. Right?

I have been assuming this for a long time, and I just need to check if I'm right in my assumption.

Comment: short answer: It's okay to prove that the condition holds for all epsilon bounded above by some fixed number.

Answer (score 1):

The two versions are equivalent.

Suppose that $\forall 0<\epsilon<\alpha$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $0<\vert x-c\vert<\delta\implies \vert f(x)-f(c)\vert<\epsilon$. Then for $\epsilon\ge\alpha$, pick $\delta$ which "works for $\alpha\over 2$" - that is, such that $0<\vert x-c\vert<\delta\implies \vert f(x)-f(c)\vert<{\alpha\over 2}$. Such a $\delta$ exists, by assumption.

But clearly this $\delta$ also "works for $\epsilon$" - that is, $$0<\vert x-c\vert<\delta\implies \vert f(x)-f(c)\vert<{\alpha\over 2}<\epsilon.$$

What's really going on here is this: we have a relation "$\delta$ works for $\epsilon$", and it satisfies the property "$\delta$ works for $\epsilon_0$, and $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_0$, implies $\delta$ works for $\epsilon_1$." So saying "for every $\epsilon$, there is some $\delta$ which works for $\epsilon$" is equivalent to saying "for every $\epsilon<\alpha$, there is some $\delta$ which works for $\epsilon$" for any positive $\alpha$.

Comment: Note that this doesn't address the very interesting problem of finding the *best possible* $\delta$ which works for a given $\epsilon$, but this is another issue entirely.

Comment: When you are writing up a proof and you have decided that you prefer to focus on "really" small $\epsilon$ do it this way: *Let $\epsilon>0$.  Define $\alpha=$[tiny] and set $$\epsilon_0=\min\{\epsilon, \alpha\}.$$ etc. etc.  Therefore $$|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon_0 \leq \epsilon.$$*  That way you are simply using the conventional definition for continuity and the "tiny" argument is just a natural part of it.